# Problema com acentuação em PHP

Tags: php

Já fiz de tudo, já troquei de programa de servidor, já botei tags charset no html e no php, mas nada resolve problema, sempre aparece esse simbolo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo simples 
 index

envia.php

Comment: Você deve usar um charset HTML <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" /> no PHP <?php header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",true);?>

Comment: Caro @brunox99x e se a página for UTF-8? E se os dados que vem do banco/mysql/etc ou APIs forem UTF8? e se o banco estiver em utf8 o documento salvo em ANSI e o header estiver em iso-8859-1, o que pode causar? ... O motivo de não darmos respostas prontas dizendo algo como: "faça isto" é justamente porque codificação/codecs são mais complicados, e o melhor é entender como funciona o básico e para que servem e porque existem diferentes tipos, pq dominando isso, que por incrivel que pareça, é o básico, vai poder trabalhar com qualquer codec sem dificuldades. Espero que entenda, um otimo feriado